# Sending the modified PDF file back to server in NestJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nestjs

I want to load a pdf and edit it(the pdf already has existing editable input fields), and when I click on save pdf I want it to go back to the server(nestjs) and replace the existing file and when load pdf is clicked again, I want the updated pdf file to be previewed.

```
import React, { useState } from "react"

const PDFViewer = () => {
  const domain = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL
  const url = `${domain}/example.pdf`
  let blob = null
  const [pdfBlob, setPdfBlob] = useState(null)
  const [pdfView, setPdfView] = useState(null)

  const loadPDF = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(url)
    blob = await response.blob()
    setPdfBlob(blob)
    setPdfView(URL.createObjectURL(blob))
  }

  const savePDF = async () => {
    if (!pdfBlob) {
      console.error("No PDF data available")
      return
    }
    const downloadLink = document.createElement("a")
    downloadLink.href = URL.createObjectURL(pdfBlob)
    downloadLink.download = "example.pdf"

    // Append the download link to the body and click it programmatically
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink)
    downloadLink.click()

    // Clean up by removing the download link from the body
    document.body.removeChild(downloadLink)

    const _blob = pdfBlob
    const arrayBuffer = await _blob.arrayBuffer()
    const uint8Array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer)

    //Saving the pdf as uint8Array
    try {
      const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: "PUT",
        body: JSON.stringify({ pdfData: Array.from(uint8Array) }), // Send the Uint8Array as an array
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      })
      if (response.ok) {
        console.log("PDF saved successfully")
      } else {
        console.error("Failed to save PDF")
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error saving PDF:", error)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={loadPDF}>Load PDF</button>
      <button onClick={savePDF}>Save PDF</button>
      <div>
        {pdfView && (
          <iframe
            title="PDF Viewer"
            src={pdfView}
            width="100%"
            height="500px"
            style={{ border: "none" }}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default PDFViewer
```

So how can I implement it. Each time I want the edited pdf to be shown when clicking load pdf and when save pdf is clicked, it should save the updated pdf back to server.